# HC05 not able to bind Raspberry pi3 bluetooth mac address B8:27:FB:A4:88:12 by AT command

Tags: arduino

I am trying to bind raspberry pi Bluetooth address on hc05 and Arduino by AT command but every time I am getting the error(7)

Here is my AT command Details:

```
     AT+BIND=B8,27,FB,A4,89,12

     OK
     ERROR:(0)
     ERROR:(7)
     ERROR:(7)
     OK
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @BUBAI NAYAK, Your question is not very clear.  Please confirm the following:  (1) (a) Rpi3B+ GPIO UART Serial or (b) USB/TTL serial connected to BlueTooth serial module #1 (BTM-HM05-1), (2) Arduino Nano UART serial connected to BlueTooth serial module #2 (BTM-HTM05-2), (3) Rpi3B+ BlueTooth 4.2/BLE (RpiBt42Ble1). (4) Are you using (a) an emulator emulator such as WinTeraTerm to send the AT commands, or (b) Python 3.7.3 program to send the AT commands? (5) Do you use any "new line" control bytes, such as "\r\n" to terminate your AT command? / to continue, ...

Comment: (6) Have you initialized the BT modules in "configuration" mode, and then back to "operation" mode, before sending the AT binding command? (7) Are you sending the AT commands from Rpi, or Arduino?